# Is it a countable set?

Tags: analysis, set-theory

Given a set $X$, if all of its nonempty subsets has its mimimum element(that is : $\forall A \subseteq X, \inf{A} \in A$), can we conclude that that X is countable?

And if the answer is no, can you provide an example?

The background of this problem:

When proving that any infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, we use two properties of $\mathbb{N}$. One is that any nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has its minimum element. The other is that for specific $e \in \mathbb{N}$,$\{x\in\mathbb{N}|x\leq e\}$ has finite number of elements.

My question is that if we cancel the second restriction, can I obtain the same result?

Comment: You're asking if every well-ordering is countable. The answer is **no** - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal).

Comment: "any subset of $\mathbb N$ has its minimum element." No. Any **nonempty** subset of $\mathbb N$ has a minimum element.

Comment: While Noah is (of course) right, I don't think anyone has ever exhibited a counterexample. Can you confirm that @NoahSchweber?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Huh? I'd say "$\omega_1$" is a pretty concrete counterexample. One way to construct it is as the set of isomorphism classes of well-orderings of $\mathbb{N}$, ordered by embeddability. If that doesn't count, what exactly do you mean by "exhibit a counterexample"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Ah, its realization as that set of isomorphism classes of well orderings is totally new to me (and I didn't see it on the Wikipedia page). Plus, it looks like the OP edited the question to ask for an example. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: In fact (under Axiom of Choice) [every set can be well-ordered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_theorem), so just take an uncountable set (say $\mathbb R$) and a well-ordering on it. Having said that, it seems that @NoahSchweber 's construction works without invoking Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Even without choice, there is a well-ordered set that has cardinality not less than continuum (the same construction - classes of well-orderings of subsets of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: @mihaild . It is consistent with ZF that $no$ subset of $\Bbb R$ is bijective to $\omega_1.$ So I am curious about how to get "cardinality not less than continuum".

Comment: Trichotomy rule for well-orders: For any two well-ordered sets A,B, exactly one of these holds: A is isomorphic to an initial segment of B, or B is isomorphic to an initial segment of   A, or A is isomorphic to B. And it is not possible for every ordinal to be isomorphic to an initial segment of A .

Comment: @DanielWainfleet if no subset of $\mathbb R$ is bijective to $\omega_1$, then $\omega_1$ has cardinality not less than $\mathbb R$.